# Alternative to mint.com

Tags: rebalancing, mint.com

I am looking to ditch Quicken so I can cut my dependence on the Windows platform and have my stuff available in the cloud.

However, I'm finding a few features in mint.com lacking.  The main difficulties for me right now:

- lack of reconciling transactions to account balance: I don't trust the data as much when I can't easily spot missing or duplicate transactions
- no easy way to set up paycheck or other recurring transaction with splits
- inability to dump current portfolio holdings to CSV for analysis / rebalancing

Given the above wish list, is there anything similar to mint.com that addresses the above shortcomings?

Comment: See also: [Gratis personal finance manager](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18564/gratis-personal-finance-manager) on [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 1):

I personally like LearnVest.  I use the free mobile app on iPhone 5 as well which allows you to view all of your transactions and you can select/change their categories and set budgets for each category.  PersonalCapital has a mobile app as well that looks pretty slick but I have not tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out:

- [LearnVest.com](http://learnvest.com)
- [PersonalCapital.com](http://personalcapital.com)

There are other programs available but im confused as to what platform you're on. You said cut ties with Windows, does that mean you're moving to Mac? If so, MoneyDance, YNAB, and MoneyWell are three great programs worth checking out.